# error when updating table (crud) in laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, crud

When I get ready to edit the table I get the following error:

> "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   GET, HEAD."

```
<?php

Route::get('/crear',[

    'uses'=>'CarController@mostrar',

    'as'=>'cars.create'

]   

);

Route::post('/crear',[

    'uses'=>'CarController@crear',

    'as'=>'cars.crear'

]);

Route::get('/', 'CarController@casa' );

Route::post('cars/{id?}/editar', 'CarController@edit')->name('editarcar');

Route::post('cars/{id?}/editar', 'CarController@update');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('cars', 'CarController');
```

**In View**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Contact')

@section('content')

    <div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        <div class="well well bs-component">

            <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">

                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)

                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $error }}</div>

                @endforeach

                @if(session('status'))

                    <div class="alert alert-success">

                        {{ session('status') }}

                    </div>

                @endif

                {!! csrf_field() !!}

                <fieldset>

                    <legend>Editar </legend>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="patente" class="col-lg-label">patente</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <input type="text" name="patente"size="6" maxlength="6" class="form-control"required>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="marca" class="col-lg-label">marca</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <input type="text" name="marca" class="form-control" required> 

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="modelo" class="col-lg-label">modelo</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <input type="text" name="modelo" class="form-control" required>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="color" class="col-lg-label">color</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <input type="text" name="color" class="form-control" required>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">

                            <button class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>

                            <button type="submit" class="ntm btn-primary">Actualizar</button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </fieldset>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

@endsection
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Car;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


    public function edit($id)
    {
        $car = car::whereid($id)->firstOrFail();

        return view('edit', compact('cars'));

    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $car = car::whereid($id)->firstOrFail();

        $car->patente = $request->post('patente');

        $car->marca = $request->post('marca');

        $car->modelo = $request->post('modelo');

        $car->color = $request->post('color');

        $car->save();

        return redirect(action('CarsController@edit', $car->id))->with('status', 'El car ' . $id . ' ha sido actualizado');

    }
```

Comment: where is the `action` attribute in form...?

Comment: no action attributes in your form. you can better define the route in your action attribute like this `action="{{ route(url) }}"`

Answer (score 0):

Update your controller > edit action with correct variable compact.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $car = car::whereid($id)->firstOrFail();

    return view('edit', compact('car'));

}
```

Add a form action like `{{ route("cars.update", ['car' => $car->id]) }}` so your view looks like:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Contact')

@section('content')

    <div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        <div class="well well bs-component">

            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route("cars.update") }}" method="post">

                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)

                    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $error }}</div>

                @endforeach

                @if(session('status'))

                    <div class="alert alert-success">

                        {{ session('status') }}

                    </div>

                @endif

                {!! csrf_field() !!}

                <fieldset>

                    <legend>Editar </legend>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="patente" class="col-lg-label">patente</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <input type="text" name="patente"size="6" maxlength="6" class="form-control"required>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="marca" class="col-lg-label">marca</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <input type="text" name="marca" class="form-control" required> 

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="modelo" class="col-lg-label">modelo</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <input type="text" name="modelo" class="form-control" required>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <label for="color" class="col-lg-label">color</label>

                        <div class="col-lg-10">

                            <input type="text" name="color" class="form-control" required>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">

                            <button class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</button>

                            <button type="submit" class="ntm btn-primary">Actualizar</button>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </fieldset>

            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

@endsection
```

Comment: I have a new error Missing required parameters for [Route: cars.update] [URI: cars/{car}]. (View: /home/romina/laravel/laravel/autoapp/resources/views/edit.blade.php)

Comment: Updated solution... please make changes in controller > edit action & also correct the form action to pass parameter.

Comment: I have a new problem, when I try to edit the data and update the following error appears "SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'patente' at row 1 (SQL: update `cars` set `patente` = [{"patente":"[{\"patente\":\"[{\\\"patente\\\":\\\"[{\\\"patente\\\\":\\\\"[{\\"patente\\\\":\\\\"[{\\\\"patente\\\\":\\\"dfvfbf\\\"}]\\\\\"}]\\\\"}]\\\"}]\"}]"}], `marca` = [{"marca":"[{\"marca\":\"[{\\\"marca\\\":\\\"[{\\\\"marca\\\":\\\"[{\\\"marca\\":\\"[{\\\"marca\\\\":\\\\\\"hola\\\\\\\\"}]\\"}]\\\\\\\"}]\\\"}]\"}]"}],`cars`.`updated_at` = 2019-06-07 where `id` = 1) ◀"

Comment: Change patent field to `text` instead of string....or check the field length and increase it to 1000

Comment: Thank you very much friend, I can update but the data does not change.
Now I do not have errors but it does not change the edited data.

Comment: You are welcome! Hopefully you can debug and resolve that too. +1

Comment: After editing the field and updating, the following appears [{"patent": "hu5f6s"}] and only "hu5f6s" should appear, could you help me solve this problem please?

Comment: Post the request value for patent.